# How can I stop 'id' tags from being automatically inserted in my code?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3

I have created a partial view, the element in the partial view looks like this (Razor Code):

```
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.OtherReferenceNumber,new { @data_slmgui_name= "otherReferenceNumber", @style = "width: 45%" })

            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.OtherReferenceNumber)
        </td>
    </tr>
```

I  don't want to use id's (on `input` tags). However, when I view the page source, the `id` attribute appears for the element even though I did not add it.  Can any one please explain to me why this appears, and how I can make it stop appearing?

Below is the actual HTML output:

```
  <tr>
        <td>
            <input data-slmgui-name="otherReferenceNumber" 
                   data-val="true" 
                   data-val-length="OtherReferenceNumber max length is 100" 
                   data-val-length-max="100" 
                   id="OtherReferenceNumber" 
                   name="OtherReferenceNumber" 
                   style="width: 45%;" 
                   value="hjghj" 
            type="text">              
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: You are using the `Html` helper, so it's been added automatically for you, you can use your own helpers or  edit the original ones, they are simple T4 templates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are automatically generated by Asp.net Mvc to get rid of them do this

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.OtherReferenceNumber, new {id=""  /*more properties*/})
```

Answer (score 0):

The HtmlHelpers, `Html.TextBoxFor()` or even `Html.TextBox` will always append the `name` and `id`, if you want to have more control on it, you can easily use `<input type="text" ...>`

just like:

```
<input type="text" 
       val="@Model.OtherReferenceNumber" 
       data-slmgui-name="otherReferenceNumber" 
       style="width: 45%" />
```

But, keep in mind that, without `name` and `id` you will never get the model in your Action, and you need to navigate through the `FormsCollection` object.

I would suggest you to see some Video Tutorial on this before you commit to "not wnat to use id's" part...

through ASP.NET website Microsoft asked PluralSight to have their courses on this, and you have a [full MVC course for free](http://www.asp.net/mvc) at your disposition...